# Element within iframe's div not accessible in the current code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 2 HTML files namely `a.html` and `b.html`, One js file namely `do.js`.

Here are each the contents of each file:

**a.html:**

```
<head>
    <script src="do.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick = "doWork();">click me</button>
    <iframe src = "b.html" id = "previewFrame"></iframe>
</body>
```

**b.html (relevant part):**

```
<div id = "container"></div>
```

**do.js:**

```
function doWork(){
 var div = $('#previewFrame').contents().find('#container');
 div.html("<input type = 'text' id = 'testElem' value = '12'><script>alert(document.getElementById('testElem').value);</script>");
}
```

When I run the above code, the content of the iframe gets replaced by the text box, however the alert fails.

I get a "type error" stating that `document.getElementById`... is null.

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing in the above code?

Comment: Try to add a closing tag for the `input`, which in this case should be a self-closing tag.

Comment: Access `testElem` directly using `#previewFrame` and `#testElem`.

Comment: @Stano JS is executed, but it triggers an error, telling just created `#testElem` doesn't exist, instead of alerting `12`.

Comment: @Stano If you can, please try to test it in IE, I guess it's not working. IEs are poor to parse HTML errors. Maybe this is an IE-specific error only, we've to wait OP's response.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, you're right! Dunno why, but I tested it somehow wrong, so didn't get any error message in any browser console. But you're right, there IS that error message. My mistake, removed my wrong comments.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the Javascript function using `document`, but this object is from the parent document, not the document of the iframe, try with:

```
function doWork(){
 var a = $('#previewFrame').contents().find('body');
 a.html("<input type = 'text' id = 'testElem' value = '12'><sc"+"ript>alert($('#previewFrame').contents()[0].getElementById('testElem').value);</scr"+"ipt>");
}
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kg8YW/).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is why OP gets the error, but your fiddle code seems to work well : ). Looks like obfuscating `script` tags is an important part of the answer, maybe you add it to the answer here too.

Comment: @JonathanNaguin, Thanks for the demo, that really helped, however my scenario is such that I am not allowed to touch the "content" that is being added to b.html. Basically I cannot touch the alert code....

Comment: @Teemu The ofuscation of the `script` tag might be a problem only in Fiddle, I am not sure...

Comment: @user2583438 You can't touch the `doWork` code?? How do you pretend to solve it then?

Comment: @JonathanNaguin, I thought the issue lied in the way the stuff was being appended or maybe I needed to add some code to defer the "script" execution. If "your" solution is the only solution then thanks, I really appreciate the efforts :), will find out a way to touch the "alert" code.....

Comment: "`I cannot touch the alert code`" Maybe he's loading the value of `innerHTML` from an external source... Anyway, when testing this locally, without obfuscating at least the closing `script` tag, I get `Unterminated string` error. (Now I can also understand, why @Stano said "code is not executed"...)

Comment: @JonathanNaguin You were absolutely right with this : ). The `document` in the newly created `script` really refers to the `document` of the main page (made a simple `alert(document.title)`-test). +1 for this... Obfuscating has pprobably something to do with jQuery, if it's left out from the closing `script` tag, an error caused by jQuery occurs.

Comment: So, is it that I have to tweak the alert code? no other ways to go around this?